# Mysql latin1 turkish data and delphi 2010 utf8

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8, ado, dbexpress

I have tables collating latin1_general_ci and have turkish character values. And i can use this data on delphi 7+zeos with no problem. but i want to upgrade my delphi to 2010 version but zeos too slow as i saw. so i want to use odbc+ado or dbexpress solution.

dbexpress solution works fine , display my data as entered and write as entered table without any change to column charset. but dbexpress has problems as i saw. for example when i select * from table which has column types as varchar,decimal,int,tinyint,text give av errors on xp systems. vista and 7 does not give any error and work fine(not fully tested).

in xp systems access violation trace is
the access violation debug trace is

|7C9010E0|ntdll.dll   |            |      |RtlLeaveCriticalSection      |       |

|7E419239|USER32.dll  |            |      |CharUpperBuffW               |       |

|7E419216|USER32.dll  |            |      |CharUpperBuffW               |       |

|7C80CED0|kernel32.dll|            |      |LCMapStringW                 |       |

|7C910380|ntdll.dll   |            |      |RtlImageNtHeader             |       |

**|7C903247|ntdll.dll   |            |      |RtlConvertUlongToLargeInteger|       |**

|7C90E485|ntdll.dll   |            |      |KiUserApcDispatcher          |       |

|009A631E|Project1.exe|Unit1.pas   |TForm1|Button1Click                 |110[37]|

ado solution(dbgo) works fine but its not show my data as entered.its want everything be utf. but i don't want to convert my data to utf before test everything. how can i see my data as entered and write client side utf and store latin1(as zeos or dbexpress do).

i was tried many other options. eg. mysql side collation and charset parameters.

sorry for my bad english. i hope someone understand me.

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your situation but have you tried setting the character set of the *connection* using `SET NAMES` ? Also, you should describe the error messages you're getting.

Comment: yes tried. but my data in latin1 format. and its include turkish characters. without convert set names doesn't work fully. if you use set names you can't search turkish characters. in utf you can do. but without full test i don't want convert my data to utf

Comment: in dbexpress solution i get access violation. i tried do trace error. it is because number converting error. i have columns like decimal(20,8),double unsigned. and my primary key columns is double unsigned not null auto_increment.i will post debug trace in my xp system.

Comment: Ah, so you need to write back data as well. Well, the easiest way to sort the character problem would be migrating the tables to UTF-8, wouldn't it? Is that not possible? As for the second problem I don't know, that seems to stem from the number conversion. I remember such problems in Delphi's database connectors but the last version I worked with was Delphi 5 :)

Comment: yes you right. also connectors way so hard. as well odbc treat my primary key as where id=1.00000. this will be problem at future. anyway i hope i have to convert my all data to utf-8 with reading latin1 and utf8decode and write utf8 table againg. as i understand alter table not solve my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to migrate to 3d party solutions, like [AnyDAC](http://www.anydac.net). AnyDAC supports the following MySQL features:

- Normal and Embedded servers.
- SSL connections.
- ENUM, SET, etc data types.
- UTF8, etc character encodings.
- AUTO_INCREMENT columns.
- MySQL 5 stored procedures.
- Batch commands with multiple result sets.
- Query execution aborting.
- Array DML.

Comment: i tried anydac trial. with anydac soluiton i have to convert my all data to utf before using. as i can see before its really fast. but i prefer open source soultion. now i am using delphi 7+zeos+mysql except delphi all open source. thanks again